# Logical && Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am getting errors on the logical `&&`

```
export default function Index({children}) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)
  return (
    {isOpen && true}
  )
```

The error reads

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
```

For demonstration purpose, I have replaced my `div` with `true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It thinks you're returning an object:

```
return ({
    isOpen && true
})
```

It expects `,` or `:` after `isOpen`.

You don't need the brackets:

```
return isOpen;
```

Comment: amazing, this worked! I thought we need `{{` to tell it is JS expression in jsx?

Comment: Only in elements like `<div>{...}</div>`

Comment: fwiw, you refer to `{{` here but you were actually using `({})` so your comment above should be "why does ({}) not work in this case". The reason is your attempting to return an object but using an incorrect format for building that object. Thats the problem you solved, nothing to do with JSX syntax in this case. Hopefully that makes sense.